# Wpf C# application exception when trying to pass a parameter to NpgsqlCommand (Postgres)

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, npgsql

when I pass a parameter to NpgsqlCommand I get this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=***' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.'

I'm using VS2017 and the latest Npgsql 3.2.5.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
NpgsqlCommand ncmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
ncmd.CommandText = @"do $$
                     BEGIN
                     IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT IdClient FROM Client WHERE IdClient = @id) THEN
                     INSERT INTO Client(id) values (@id);
                     END IF;

                     END
                     $$ ";

ncmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Comment: How did you install Npgsql? System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions is indeed a dependency of Npgsql, if you're using nuget everything should be working out of the box. It sounds like you're taking a direct reference on Npgsql.dll rather than using proper package management to install.

Comment: I installed Npgsql with the Nuget Package Manager

Comment: Running in debug mode or as a deployed application?

Comment: Error happens running in Debug mode

Comment: If nobody knows the solution to this problem is there maybe some other forum that is more suitable for Npgsql related questions?

Comment: I am asking this the wrong way??